# can't change keyboard layout to german on ubuntu server

Tags: server, virtualbox, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I have a fresh installed ubuntu server in a virtualBox and am trying to set the keyboard layout to german, but don't succeed. I have installed and configured

```
dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
dpkg-reconfigure console-data
dpkg-reconfigure console-setup
```

The settings for keyboard-configuration are:

```
Generische Keyboard with 105 keys (Intl)
German
German
```

For example, the key that should be

```
- is `ß`
[ and ] doesn't work at all (as well as all of the other keys used with alt-right)
```

How can I fix this? I am running several servers and never had that issue. Is it a virtualbox bug/misconfiguration?

EDIT:

During installation there's an option to autodetect the keyboard's layout. One step asks for pressing `ö`, but that key isn't recognized either.

Comment: You may have to logout and -in again. At least it was like this on my Debian text-only recovery system.

Comment: I've tried it, but it still doesn't work. Some of the keys aren't recognized at all I guess.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as you and `loadkeys de` did the trick. For other languages:

- Spanish: `loadkeys es`
- Portuguese: `loadkeys pt`
- Brazilian Portuguese: `loadkeys br`
- Swiss German: `loadkeys ch`

Note, that these settings don't survive a reboot.